# @RepositoryRestResource sub path configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

Is it possible to segment different **@RepositoryRestResource** using different sub paths?

Let me explain a little more:

- I have some repositories related to authorization
- I have other repositories related to notifications (mail, sms)

What I want is the first group of resources use the path **"/api/auth"** and the second group use **"/api/notif"**.

An important point to consider is that the entities that those repositories use are related, for example, every notification has a sender, and the sender is a entity related to the authorization repo.

Thanks in advance.